# Why is my code exiting as soon as I start it?

Tags: python

I have a pygame project where I need to display a button according to a randomly generated sequence. It is currently just exiting as soon as I start it

```
import pygame
import os
import random

# Initialize pygame starts 
pygame.init()

# Set the dimensions of the screen
screen_width = 1275
screen_height = 750


# Set the colors
white = (255, 255, 255)
black = (0, 0, 0)

# Set the font
font = pygame.font.SysFont('Arial', 20)

# Set the button properties
button_radius = 70
button_x_spacing = 400
button_y_spacing = 200

# Set the flower image
flower_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents", "flower.jpg"))
flower_rect = flower_image.get_rect()
flower_rect.center = (screen_width//2, screen_height//2)

# Set the button positions
button_positions = [
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 200),
    (button_x_spacing, button_y_spacing + 400)
]

# Initialize the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))

# Set the caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Marmoset Buttons")

# Set the clock
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# Set the loop variable
running = True

# Set the timer
timer = 0

# Generating sequence of numbers
sequence = [0,1,2,1,2,0,2,1,0,2]

for i in sequence:
    # Check for events
    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            distance_button = pygame.math.Vector2(button_positions[i]) - pygame.math.Vector2(pygame.mouse.get_pos())
            flower_image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Documents", f"flower{i}.jpg"))
            if distance_button.length() < button_radius:
                timer = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    screen.fill(black)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, white, button_positions[i], button_radius)
    text_surface = font.render(f"Button {i}", True, black)
    text_rect = text_surface.get_rect(center=button_positions[i])
    screen.blit(text_surface, text_rect)
   
    # Check the timer
    if timer != 0:
        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time - timer < 3000:
            screen.blit(flower_image, flower_rect)
        else:
            timer = 0

    pygame.display.update()

# Quit pygame
pygame.quit()
```

I tried commenting some previous unnecessary code I had but nothing is changing. I had it working before where I displayed all 3 buttons at once but when I tried changing it to randomly show one it didn't work.

Comment: This code won't run at all, because it has indentation errors...

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with the commenting the beginning of the main loop and leaving the rest of the code not shifted to the beginning of the row.

Now your main code, starting with

```
# Main game loop
#while running:
    # Set the frame rate
    #clock.tick(60)

    for i in sequence:
    # Check for events
        screen.fill(black)
```

is located INSIDE the upper loop that is executed 10 times.

With the existing comments you'd rather shift

```
   for i in sequence:
```

and the rest to the left.

The better approach - instead of commented rows at the beginning add something like `for` or `while` loop executed as much times as you meed -- just to keep the same identation.

Comment: thanks yea im more used to c++ and java so im not as well versed in python indentation. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @krai28: once you get used to the indentation, it is actually very clean...  But this is a typical semantic error that the coder has to be aware of.